# KeyError Received unregistered task of type '' on celery while task is registered

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, celery, celery-task

I'm a bit new in celery configs.

I have a task named `myapp.tasks.my_task` for example.

I can see `myapp.tasks.my_task` in registered tasks of celery when I use `celery inspect registered`. doesn't it mean that the task is successfully registered? why it raises the following error for it:

```
KeyError celery.worker.consumer.consumer in on_task_received

Received unregistered task of type 'my_app.tasks.my_task'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?

Please see
http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html
for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
'[[], {}, {"callbacks": null, "errbacks": null, "chain": null, "chord": null}]' (77b)
```

there are also other tasks in `my_app.tasks` and they work correctly but only this task does not work and gets **KeyError**:

```
@shared_task(queue='celery')
def other_task():
   """ WORKS """
   ...

@shared_task(queue='celery')
def my_task():
   """ DOES NOT WORK """
   ...
```

Comment: Can you share your celery app's configuration file? The one where you defined an instance of e.g. `app = Celery("my_app")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Back in the day, when I faced the problem a senior solved it for me in a mushroom management way unfortunately (see more about this anti-pattern [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mushroom_management#:%7E:text=Mushroom%20management%20is%20the%20management,affect%20their%20work%20and%20employment.)).
I came back to this problem recently to figure out the solution in our own project domain.

As Niel pointed in his/her [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68891943/12311820), we were using `celery_app.autodiscover_tasks()` in our project and in that case we should import `my_task` in `__init__.py` of `tasks` package like bellow.

```py
from .some_tasks_file import my_task
```

Also, we used celery beat and the task defined inside `app.conf.beat_schedule` must have exact path to the function like bellow (even though the function is imported in `__init__.py` of the `tasks` package).

```py
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'MY_TASK': {
        'task': 'myapp.tasks.some_tasks_file.my_task',
        'schedule': 60,  # every minute
    },
}
```

Hope this would help people with the same celery configuration and problem.

Answer (score 8):

It means that Celery can't find the implementation of the task `my_app.tasks.my_task` when it was called. Some possible solutions you may want to look at:

#### Possible Solution 1:

You probably haven't configured correctly either:

- Celery [imports](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std-setting-imports) e.g. `celery_app.conf.update(imports=['my_app.tasks'])` or `celery_app.conf.imports = ['my_app.tasks']`
- Or Celery [include](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.html#celery-application-objects) ([example](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/next-steps.html#proj-celery-py)) e.g. `celery_app = Celery(..., include=['my_app.tasks'])`

Note: If in a Django application, this can be skipped if already using `celery_app.autodiscover_tasks()` since the tasks are automatically discovered in the location `./<app_name>/tasks.py`

#### Possible Solution 2:

If you are only importing `my_app` e.g. `celery_app.conf.update(imports=['my_app'])` then I assume you have a file **my_app/__init__.py** Make sure that inside that file, it imports the task `my_app.tasks.my_task` along with `my_app.tasks.other_task` so that the celery app knows that such task exists.

```
# Contents of my_app/__init__.py
from my_app.tasks import (
    my_task,
    other_task,
)
```

#### Possible Solution 3:

In case the `my_task` was just newly added (whereas `other_task` was already an old existing task), you might not have restarted the celery worker yet to see the new task. Try restarting the worker.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution can be adding a `name` param in the `shared_task` decorator, i.e.,

```py
@shared_task(queue='celery', name='other_task')
def other_task():
   """ WORKS """
   ...

@shared_task(queue='celery', name='my_task')
def my_task():
   """ DOES NOT WORK """
   ...
```

I see this in a full demo project https://github.com/melikesofta/django-dynamic-periodic-tasks, and the related code can be find [here](https://github.com/melikesofta/django-dynamic-periodic-tasks/blob/main/setups/tasks.py#L6).

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the error by just restarting **Celery**. I use **Celery 5.1.2**:

```
celery -A core worker --pool=solo -l info
```